# Regarding Where clause- SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a  question regarding WHERE clauses in `SQLite`. I have worked on `SQLite` however I'm having trouble with `WHERE` clauses.

I want to select the rows where KEY_TAG = ch.
my query

```
String selectQuery = ("SELECT * FROM"+ TABLE_QUEST+ "WHERE"+ KEY_TAG+  "='" + ch+ "'");
Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

here ch is of string type.

Query runs yet no rows are returned i.e empty cursor.
I have tried all the permutations but none working for me..
Help..!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add some space after FROM, before and after WHERE like "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_QUEST+ " WHERE "+ KEY_TAG+ "='" + ch+ "'"

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_QUEST+ " WHERE "+ KEY_TAG+ "='" + ch+ "'";
```